# Как получить определённый текст из url запроса в php переменную

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Как получить определённый текст из url запроса в php переменную. У меня есть url запрос в котором нужно прописать user?id="**любое число**" и как я могу получить это число в переменную? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$userId = $_GET["id"];
```